Overscroll on ListView when calling scrollController.animateTo
I have a ListView.builder like so:
ListView.builder(
  key: _listViewKey,
  controller: widget.scrollController,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: state.items,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  ...

Additionally I have a scroll to the end method that uses the scrollController to call animateTo to take the user to the bottom of the list regardless of where they are scrolled to. Here is that method:
void scrollToEnd() async {
   await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
   Future.doWhile(() {
     if (widget.scrollController.positions.last.extentAfter == 0) {
       return Future.value(false);
     }
     return widget.scrollController.animateTo(widget.scrollController.positions.last.maxScrollExtent, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.linear).then((value) => true);
   });
}

I found that calling animateTo only once wasnt always enough and sometimes the scroll didnt go all the way to the bottom so this doWhile method was developed.
However now when scrolling up the list a few items and evoking scrollToEnd() there seems to be a pretty severe overscroll and total whitespace is shown until eventually the last list items sinks back down into view. I have 2 questions:

Why is widget.scrollController.positions.last.maxScrollExtent ever returning a higher value than the list actually has?
How can I stop this overscroll from happening? My only goal is that scrollToEnd() gets the list to the end every time and that is doesnt look wonky when it does it.

Edit: The heights of all the list items vary so I need a solution that doesnt work on hardcoded fixed heights.

Why do you need AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()?

Can you add pics or gif explaining your prblm. There are many ways to do go to end of the list. One is to use global key for last item in listview and use Scrollable.ensureVisible(key) ; but this should be your last option. If you can better explain this overscroll, then only I can give further assistance.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, which is to reach the end of the list, just change your _scrollToEnd function and ensure that it will only be called after the widget is built.
Code
void _scrollToEnd() {
  widget.scrollController.animateTo(
    widget.scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.linear,
  );
}


Let's imagine you have a very long list. When this animation occurs, you handle it with a while loop. Not only does the scrollController.animateTo() get triggered multiple times, but the ListView.builder() also attempts to build everything for the children that haven't been built yet, especially if there are expensive widgets or images. That's why this "white space" occurs.
I've also successfully reproduced the issue where the ListView builder cannot scroll to its maximum scroll. In this image, it can only scroll to 947 despite the list length being 1000.

here the fix :
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListExample> createState() => _ListExampleState();
}

class _ListExampleState extends State<ListExample> {
  final sc = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    sc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  late int count;

  Future<void> scrollToBottom() {
    count ++;
    print("scrolling $count times");
    return sc.animateTo(sc.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }

  void scrollToBottomFix() {
    count = 0;
    
    Future.doWhile(
      () async {
        await scrollToBottom();
        if (sc.offset >= sc.position.maxScrollExtent) {
          print("max scroll position is achieved");
          return false;
        }
        print("max scroll position is NOT achieved");
        return true;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final image = SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        child: Image.network(
          'https://source.unsplash.com/random',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ));

    const length = 1000;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed:()=> scrollToBottomFix(), child: const Text('scroll to bottom'))
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: sc,
        itemCount: length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('item ${index + 1}'),
            tileColor: index.isEven ? Colors.black26 : Colors.black12,
            subtitle:
                Random().nextBool() ? image : const Text("Lorem Ipsum..."),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


The AlwaysScrollablePhysics by default has a bouncing scroll physics, which causes the scroll controller to return a higher max scroll value. You can diminish the over scroll and also get precise values of the max scroll from scroll controller by clamping it.
You can clamp the scroller as follows while keeping the always scroll physics:
physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(
            parent: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          ),


Having AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() will always cause your List to overscroll, moreover users may have issues with that too. If you want bouncing effect that causes your list to overscroll by a little bit but then come back you can use BouncingScrollPhysics. Sometimes though it does not work properly, then it is best to add parent physics like this:
const BouncingScrollPhysics(
  parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
),

You can of scroll to the bottom of the list by getting maxScrollExtent from widget.scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent. Trying to get it from positions will not always work best for List that uses builder constructor. Then your function would look like this:
void scrollToEnd() {
  widget.scrollController.animateTo(
    widget.scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  );
}

If you know what element is your last element when building a List you can add a GlobalKey to it, which you will store in your state method and then call ensureVisible:
void scrollToEnd() {
  if (_globalKey.currentContext != null) {
    Scrollable.ensureVisible(globalKey.currentContext!)
  }
}

